# Power button not working. Phone wont boot?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-ace, recovery-mode

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace GTS 5830i.

I somehow messed up the power button of my phone and now after the battery drained completely, It will not start.

I tried looking up online for going into recovery mode (without using the power button) i.e keeping home key pressed while inserting the charging but nothing works. Finally, I thought I must have an option to boot up my phone through Eclipse DDMS but I cant find any option there either ([See screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/Sb7AkoAN))

Please help.

---

EDIT : Thanks to the answer by Sparx, I have solved this problem. Connect the phone via USB to your computer. If you have installed the Android SDK, go in the android-tools folder and execute adb devices (if on a mac, run ./adb devices)

If your devices shows up in the list run ./adb reboot

Comment: Have you tried plugging in the charger? or else plugging in the charger and while plugged in, remove and then re-insert battery. Some phones tend to start up in that manner.

Comment: Also if you can connect via adb (even if your phone is powered down), the "adb devices" // "adb reboot" ought to start your phone. If you're rooted, there are apps like Quick Reboot that allow you to reboot to Recovery or Download mode with a tap, provided you have CWM.

Comment: ADB reboot works ! Thank you. If this were an answer, i'd have accepted it.

Comment: @Sparx Consider making your comment an answer, as the OP already edited the question mentioning that the issue was solved thanks to your information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried plugging in the charger? or else plugging in the charger and while plugged in, remove and then re-insert battery. Some phones tend to start up in that manner.

Also if you can connect via adb (even if your phone is powered down), the `adb devices` followed by `adb reboot` ought to start your phone. If you're rooted, there are apps like Quick Reboot that allow you to reboot to Recovery or Download mode with a tap, provided you have CWM.

Answer (score -1):

You need to first plug your phone then insert the battery. I have followed this on my HTC Desire phone.